# Can I pass WeakReference to the Observable listeners?

Tags: java, observer-pattern, weak-references

I'm fixing a legacy application which has problem with objects being retained by list of Observers in a class implementing Observable. Properly removing the Observers would be a lengthy task, so I thought I could use `WeakReference` to overcome this. The problem is, that calling `Observable.addObserver(new WeakReference(something))` is not possible since `WeakReference` doesn't implement Observer. So I thought of creating class called `WeakObserver` like this:

```
public class WeakObserver<T> extends WeakReference<T> implements Observer {
private T observer;

public WeakObserver(final T observer){
    super(observer);
    this.observer = observer;
}

@Override
public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
    ((Observer)observer).update(o, arg);
}
}
```

The problem here is quite obvious - apart from not safe cast in `update` method, I'm creating another reference to the object which I want to get garbage collected.

Is something like this even possible, or am I trying to do something stupid?

Comment: So it is the `Observer` objects that you want to allow to be GC'd, and the problem is that they are enrolled in the `Observable`'s list?

Comment: Yes, exactly. The only thing I can think of is reimplementing `Observable` methods to use `WeakReference<Observer>` objects

Comment: Does WeakObserver need to have the instance variable observer? Why not rely on the get() method of WeakReference in the update method - check if null and if not delegate the call to the non-null reference?

Comment: People still use the Observer interface?  I don't mean the Observer *pattern*, just the Java interface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can probably make this work, but you want your weak observables to *have* weak references to the real `Observable`s, not to *be* weak references.

Moreover, it's not enough to allow the real observers to be GC'd; you also need to unregister the wrapper objects from the `Observable` once that happens.  This sort of thing is what reference queues are for, but if you don't want to modify the `Observable` class then you can shortcut like this:

```
public class WeakObserver implements Observer {
    private final WeakReference<Observer> observer;
    private final Observable observed;

    public WeakObserver(Observer observer, Observable observed){
        this.observer = new WeakReference<Observer>(observer);
        this.observed = observed;
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
        Observer realObserver = observer.get();

        if (realObserver != null) {
            realObserver.update(o, arg);
        } else {
            observed.deleteObserver(this);
        }
    }
}
```

That `WeakObserver` is specific to a single `Observable`, as is necessary to get it automatically removed when the underlying real `Observer` is GC'd.  You could avoid that by use of a `ReferenceQueue` if you were willing and able to modify the `Observable` appropriately.

Comment: This is probably the solution I'm looking for. I'm still not able to get the GC to clear those Observers, but they are probably referenced somewhere else so I have to dig into heap dump.

Answer (score 3):

(To build off of my comment) Rather than holding onto a reference, you can rely on the get method of WeakReference. The class could also be parametized so the cast is not necessary in the update method:

```
private class ObserverWeak extends WeakReference<Observer> implements Observer{

    public ObserverWeak(Observer referent) {
        super(referent);
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Observable obs, Object arg) {
        if ( super.get() != null ){
            super.get().update(obs, arg);
        }
    }


}
```